# How to extract a windows cabinet file in python

Tags: python

Is it somehow possible to extract .cab files in python?

Answer (score 2):

Not strictly answering what you asked, but if you are running on a windows platform you could spawn a process to do it for you.

Taken from Wikipedia:

> Microsoft Windows provides two
>   command-line tools for creation and
>   extraction of CAB files. They are
>   MAKECAB.EXE (included within Windows
>   packages such as 'ie501sp2.exe' and
>   'orktools.msi'; also available from
>   the SDK, see below) and EXTRACT.EXE
>   (included on the installation CD),
>   respectively. Windows XP also provides
>   the EXPAND.EXE command.

Comment: 10 years late, but this is what I currently use to extract cab files in Windows and it seems to work: `subprocess.run(['expand', 'file.cab', 'extracted.file'])`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem last week so I implemented this in python. Comments, additions and especially pull requests welcome: https://github.com/hughsie/python-cabarchive

Comment: I also tried implementing it in python; but I didn't understand the LZX compression.  The documentation that MS put out didn't help.

Comment: Are there any examples on how to extract or pack with python-cabarchive?  I can't seem to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly, the [msilib](http://docs.python.org/library/msilib.html) can only create or append to .CAB files, but not extract them. :(

However, the [hachoir](https://hachoir.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parser.html) parser module can apparently read & edit Cabinets. (I have not used it, though, so I couldn't tell you how fitting it is or not!)

Comment: Updated the link to the current hachoir.parser documentation at https://hachoir.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parser.html

Comment: I've also played around with `msilib` and can confirm it can only create CAB files, and only with MSZIP compression.  No LZX compression (yet), and no extract method so far.